# SoapUI groovy script build string on condition

Tags: string, groovy, soapui

I have this string

```
log.info("My name is :" + name)
```

where name is a predefined String.

Now name can be either Peter or Mary depending on some boolean X. So result can be "My name is Mary" if X is true or "My name is Peter" if X is false.  Now I know I can predetermine 'name' before doing log.info, but what if I wanted to do that within the same line?  Something like:

```
log.info("My name is: " + if (X) then "Mary" else "Peter")
```

The above will give me unexpected token "+"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite simple. You can use [ternary operator](http://groovy-lang.org/operators.html#_ternary_operator)

```
log.info("My name is: " + X ? "Mary" : "Peter")
```

Comment: Yep that's in.  I'm pretty sure I tried and was getting an error, but I tried again now and works fine.  I must have been doing something stupid :D.  Thanks for your answer!